# Ayuda con ejercicio de calculo en horas en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, programación-móvil

En este ejercicio, tengo que iniciar con una hora de entrada (ejemplo: 20:30), posterior a ello, tengo que sumar los minutos para obtener la hora de salida.

Pero tengo dos detalles los cuales no se cuales son, el primero me indica un error de "Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'long', required: 'int" y el segundo "Cannot resolve method 'makeText" ¿A que se deberán?

```
    package com.example.yasna.myapp_ejerciciohoras;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edtH1;
    private EditText edtM1;
    private EditText edtM2;
    private EditText edtH2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtH1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHora);
        edtM1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMin1);
        edtM2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMin2);
        edtH2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHora2);

    }

    public void calcularHora(View view){




        String Hora =edtH1.getText().toString() ; // sin espacio
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        Date horas = null;
        try {
            horas = formato.parse(Hora);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String horasformato = formato.format(horas);

        /************/
        Calendar HoraFinal=Calendar.getInstance();
        HoraFinal.setTime(horas);



        /***********/



        int min= Integer.parseInt(edtM1.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(edtM2.getText().toString());


        String formato2 = "%02d:%02d" ;
        long horasReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(min);
        long minutosReales = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(min) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(min));

        HoraFinal.add(Calendar.HOUR, horasReales);
        HoraFinal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutosReales);


        Toast.makeText(this, HoraFinal.getTime(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, String.format(formato2, horasReales, minutosReales),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//aqui







       Toast.makeText(this,horasformato,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    }
}
```

Comment: el primer error te dice que espera un entero per tu le envias un ` long horasReales ` cambialos a `int horasReales` y el el toast espera como segundo argumento un string y tu estasetenado un objeto Calendar tienes que convertirlo a string

Comment: Donde le agrego el string del calendar?

Comment: prueba: `Toast.makeText(this, String.vlaueof(HoraFinal.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: y la primera quedaría así? int horasReales = (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(min);
        int minutosReales = (int) (TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(min) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(min)));